# Azure製品がセキュリティ要件を満たしているのか知りたい

Tags: security, azure

Azureの下記サービスの使用を検討しています。

- Azure SQL Database
- Azure Storage

上記のサービスが下記のセキュリティ評価を満たしているかご存知でしょうか？
調べてみたのですが、情報がありませんでした。ユーザ様のセキュリティ要件に
該当する内容ですので何卒ご回答をお願いします。

**セキュリティ要件:**

- データセンターがティア４以上
- ISMSクラウドセキュリティ認証(ISO27001／ISO27017)規格を取得していること

情報が記載されているサイトのURLを記載して頂ければ非常にありがたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[監査レポート](https://servicetrust.microsoft.com/ViewPage/MSComplianceGuide)のISO Reportsを参照すると、認証ごとのレポート、サービスごとの取得状況が確認できます。

一方、Uptime Instituteによるデータセンタの認証（Tier 1/2/3/4）は、オフィシャルな取得状況は公開されていないようです。
Azureはデータセンタが具体的には非公表ということになっているせいですかね、分かりませんが。
[データセンターのセキュリティの概要](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/compliance/assurance/assurance-datacenter-security)といった情報から、要件を満たすか確認する必要があると考えます。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: 返信ではなく、回答です。回答のうち、質問を解決するものにはチェックをお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

関連しそうなドキュメントで見つかったものは以下になります。

[Azure コンプライアンス ドキュメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/compliance/)

> ISO 27001, ISO 27017

[Azure Storage のコンプライアンス認証](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/storage/common/storage-compliance-offerings)

> ISO 27001

[Azure の施設、建物、および物理上のセキュリティ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/security/fundamentals/physical-security)

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
参考にさせていただきます。